# How to generate an OpenVPN 4096 or 8192 bit static key?

Tags: rsa, openvpn

How to create an OpenVPN static / pre-shared key with key size 4096 or 8192 bit?

```
openvpn --genkey
```

Creates 2048 bit strong keys only.

Static key. Not CA.

Comment: The pre-shared secrets aren't asymmetric keys, they're four 512 bit keys for symmetric ciphers and hmacs.

Answer (score 3):

The static keys are used to derive symmetric keys and authentication keys. There is no need to have a larger key. In fact, it would have been perfectly fine if OpenVPN used a 256-bit static key and used a KDF (Key-Derivation Function) to expand it into however many bits it needs. It's important to know that symmetric cryptography differs from asymmetric cryptography in that you only need enough bits to make exhaustive search impossible. Larger key sizes do not meaningfully improve security.

According to [OpenVPN documentation](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/openvpn-cryptographic-layer/), the 2048-bit key houses four independent keys which are used for encryption and authentication. You can't increase the size because no more bits are needed. In fact, each key is 512 bits in size to allow for future encryption and HMAC keys of larger sizes. They only all used only when HMAC is used for integrity encryption is directional (`key-direction` is used). By default, only one encryption key and one HMAC key is used, and it is used in both directions. Only as many bits as required are read from each 512-bit key.

Below is an example static key using a 128-bit symmetric cipher and HMAC-SHA1 for integrity:

```
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
eac9ae92cd73c5c2d6a2338b5a22263a <- 128 bits for cipher
4ef4a22326d2a996e0161d25d41150c8
38bebc451ccf8ad19c7d1c7ce09742c3
2047ba60f1d97d47c88f7ab0afafb2ce
f702cb04c7d15ff2606736c1825e830a <- 160 bits for HMAC-SHA1
7e30a7964b82825d6767a04b3c8f4583
d4928127262c3a8603776bd6da339f69
dece3bbfee35f1dceb7cbceaef4c6933
2c2cef8ac550ed15213b216b825ab31e
49840f99ff9df3c5f31156439ed6b99c
4fc1bff417d33d77134365e38c9d71cd
e294ba6e65d51703d6d4a629d5fc618e
adddb889b8173ac79b4261328770bbbe
74294bc79e357c82af9ef53f2968be6a
007e6022da0a1a39f2ed5660f94a5926
35d72e5838dd78dd680d91f6edcf6988
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
```

You can see that only the key material that is needed is used. The rest is ignored. In fact, even [modifying key material](https://openvpn.net/faq/changed-hex-bytes-in-the-static-key-the-key-still-connects-to-a-remote-peer-using-the-original-key/) doesn't necessarily prevent the remote peer from connecting. If you created a larger key, it would not provide you with any extra security whatsoever.